# How to arrange all fieldset elements on one line?

Tags: html, css, visualforce

I have a form composed of 3 fieldsets, and I want to display all individual elements on the same line, meaning:

< input> To < input > < input> < checkbox> < checkbox> < checkbox> ...

Instead of the way it is now:
[image]

So basically, I need to move the contents of the first fieldset into a single line.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="filtersDiv" >
    <fieldset class="reservationFiltersCheckinDates"><legend>{!$Label.check_in}</legend>
    <apex:inputField value="{!reservationSearchCriteria.Check_In__c}"
        id="reservationSearchCheckInStart" onchange="changeValues()"
        styleClass="ajaxableElem" /> {!$Label.to} <apex:inputField value="{!reservationSearchCriteria.Check_Out__c}"
        id="reservationSearchCheckInEnd" onchange="changeValues()"
        styleClass="ajaxableElem" /></fieldset>
    <fieldset class="reservationFiltersSearch"><legend>{!$Label.nameOrReservationId}</legend>

    <input type="text" value="{!reservationSearchText}"
        id="reservationSearchText" onfocus="this.oldvalue = this.value;"
        onkeyup="showAjax(this);changeValues();" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
                        // have to do it here, as this change is lost of partial page refresh, and
                        // we can't add placeholder attribute directly to visualforce tags 
                        j$(document).ready(function() {
                          j$("[id*='reservationSearchText']").attr('placeHolder', 'Search');
                        });                                                      
                    </script></fieldset>
    <fieldset class="reservationFiltersStatus"><legend>{!$Label.status}</legend>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="{!pendingResCheck1}"
        id="pendResCheckID" onchange="changeValues()" checked="true"
        class="ajaxableElem" />{!$Label.pending}</label> <label><input
        type="checkbox" value="{!checkedInResCheck}" id="checkedInResCheckID"
        onchange="changeValues()" checked="true" class="ajaxableElem" />{!$Label.checkedin}</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="{!cancelledResCheck}"
        id="cancelledResCheckID" onchange="changeValues()" checked="true"
        class="ajaxableElem" />{!$Label.canceled}</label> <label><input
        type="checkbox" value="{!confirmResCheck}" id="confirmResCheckID"
        onchange="changeValues()" checked="true" class="ajaxableElem" />{!$Label.confirmed}</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="{!checkedOutResCheck}"
        id="checkedOutResCheckID" onchange="changeValues()" checked="true"
        class="ajaxableElem" />{!$Label.checkedout}</label></fieldset>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#filtersDiv
{
    margin: 10px 0 5px 0 !important;
}
#filtersDiv fieldset
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: none;
}
#filtersDiv fieldset legend
{
    font-size: 14px !important;
}
```

Comment: Please post the generated HTML, not whatever language that is.

Comment: This is Visualforce (HTML for Salesforce), and the reason for this mess was that they override CSS markup for many elements. Anyway, James Donnelly solved this for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply set all the child elements of fieldset to be displayed as `inline-block`:

```
fieldset > * {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/uESBC/1/).

Comment: I narrowed this down a bit, replacing fieldset with the id of the specific fieldset I wanted to fix. And it works! Thanks James